# how to scrape data from websites which uses just one url

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

i am a student and i'm trying to scrape data from our online register so that a discord bot can send the informations on discord, the website requires login which i was able to do with this code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html


session_requests = requests.session()
login_url ="url"
result = session_requests.get(login_url)


payload = {
    "txtUser": "user", 
    "txtPassword": "pass"}


tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
        )
```

but then when i started to scrape data i encountered an issue: the website uses just one url, to explain it better imagine if you needed to scrape data from stackoverflow.com but the url in the address bar is always just stackoverflow.com/ even when you visit other pages of the website like ask question or the bountied questions' page

i don't know how i could retrieve data from something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website acts like a single-page application, I can think of two ways I might try to approach the problem:

Option 1: Try to reverse-engineer the API calls the web page makes. Open the site in Chrome and open the developer tools `(CTRL+SHIFT+I)` and then watch the Network tab as you click around the site. It should show you all the requests the page makes back to their server. Depending on how complex it is, this may be easy to understand, or it may be completely inscrutable. Maybe you can find API endpoints like [www.school.edu/classinfo/1234](http://www.school.edu/classinfo/1234) that you can use directly to get data. Play with a tool like Postman and see if you can recreate some of the API calls. If you don't have any good leads within a few minutes, move on to option 2.

Option 2: Look at a browser automation tool like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). The most common use for Selenium is automated testing for websites, but you can also use it with Python to perform actions on a webpage, and then interrogate the resulting document state.  (ex: open this site; find the text field with the id "studentid"; type my student id into that field; find the button with the id "viewschedule"; click it; find the div with the id "schedule"; return the text from inside that div). Some good places to start are the [selenium-python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) docs and a pretty good "[getting started](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/python-selenium-to-run-web-automation-test)" blog post. You can just tune out when they start talking about testing frameworks.

Comment: so i tried to reverse-engenner it and it sends one request per button pressed on the site so i did a ctrl-shift-i and i copied the headers of the request, putted them into a dict and sent them with a request like [this](https://hastebin.com/veyeyobeba.http) but i get this [error](https://hastebin.com/guhaxeduji.sql)